# Why is $\mathbb{R}^2/G$ homeomorphic to the Klein bottle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, klein-bottle

Let $G$ be the group of transformation generated by $a,b:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ where $a(x,y)=(x+1,y-1)$ and $b(x,y)=(x,y+1)$.

We note than $bab=a$ and that $G$ acts properly discontinuously on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2/G$ is a covering map.

Comment: Your maps are incorrect. Given the group $G$ acting on $\Bbb R^2$ as you wrote down, the quotient $\Bbb R^2/G$ is going to be a torus and the relation $ab = ba$ will hold. (you can check the former by drawing a picture, or alternately check the relation algebraically)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_polygon